# How to find random values of variable satisfying multiple conditions?

Tags: random, conditional

I have multiple conditions to be satisfied

```
Abs[x] < 1 && 
 Abs[x] < (1 - 2 Sqrt[Abs[y]] Sqrt[(1 + Abs[y]) (1 + Abs[z])] + 
   Abs[y] (2 + Abs[z]))/Abs[z] && Abs[y] < 1 && Abs[z] < 1
```

and I want to find random numerical values of (x,y,z) which satisfies all the above conditions?

I tried using FindInstance but it didn't generate random values.

Comment: use `RealAbs` instead of `Abs` to speed up the calculate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) + [`RandomPoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html):

```
impreg = ImplicitRegion[Abs[x] < (1 - 2 Sqrt[Abs[y]] Sqrt[(1 + Abs[y]) (1 + Abs[z])] + 
              Abs[y] (2 + Abs[z]))/Abs[z], 
  {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1,  1}}];

RandomPoint[impreg]
```

> ```
>  {-0.765127, -0.0412526, 0.134246}
> ```

```
SeedRandom[1]
randompoints = RandomPoint[impreg, 20];

Show[RegionPlot3D[impreg, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.3]], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[#, .05] & /@ randompoints}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

We can modified the inequalities to speed up the calculate. Use `RealAbs` instead of `Abs` for real numbers.

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[
   RealAbs[x] RealAbs[z] < 
    1 - 2 Sqrt[RealAbs[y]] Sqrt[(1 + RealAbs[y]) (1 + RealAbs[z])] + 
     RealAbs[y] (2 + RealAbs[z]), {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 
     1}}] // Region
RandomPoint[reg, 1000]
```

[image]

Furthermore, by the symmetric we can assuming that  `x>=0 && y>=0 && z>=0` and randomly select the sign of the coordinate.

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[
    x*z < 1 - 2 Sqrt[y] Sqrt[(1 + y) (1 + z)] + y (2 + z), {{x, 0, 
      1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}] // Region;
Graphics3D[{Cyan, Point[RandomPoint[reg, 10000]]}]
```

Comment: If you execute `a = ListPointPlot3D[RandomPoint[reg, 1000]];Show[{reg, a}]`, then you see points outside `reg`.